# Avoid hyphenation of BibLaTeX labels

Tags: biblatex, hyphenation

Based on the `labelalpha` style, I defined by own BibLaTeX label, which consists of the first author's full name and the date of the publication. However, if the author's name is long and the citation is near the end of the lines, the label is hyphenated. A MWE looks like this:

```
\documentclass[%
   12pt,             
   english        
   paper = A4          
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Verylongname_74,
  author = {Verylongname, Tom S. and Longname, Bob C.},
  year = {1974},
  title = {The economics of brushing teeth},
  journal = {Journal of Political Economy},
  volume = {82},
  number = {4},
  pages = {887--891},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[%
  citestyle = alphabetic, 
  labelalpha = true,
  defernumbers = true,
  backend = biber, 
  maxalphanames = 1,
  firstinits = true
]{biblatex}%

% own BibLaTeX label definition -------------------------------

\renewcommand*{\labelalphaothers}{+}

\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{shorthand}
    \field[compound=false]{labelname}
    \field{label}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \literal{\addnbthinspace}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \field[strwidth=2,strside=right]{year}
  }
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalphawidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

% avoid hyphenation, not working!
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalpha}{\nohyphenation #1}

%--------------------------------------------------------------

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

This is a  line of text. This is a line of text. An example citation here is
\cite{Verylongname_74}.  The BibLaTeX  label, which is the
author's name, is hyphenated!

\end{document}
```

How can I tell BibLaTeX not to hyphenate labels?

[image]

Comment: Try `\AtEveryCitekey{\hyphenrules{nohyphenation}}` in your preamble. http://mrunix.de/forums/showthread.php?76615-biblatex-Trennung-von-Namen-im-Flei%DFtextes&p=359881&viewfull=1#post359881

Comment: Hm, I get the error: ERROR: Package babel Error: You haven't defined the language nohyphenation yet. ?

Comment: `babel` is not loaded in your example.

Comment: @Johannes_B Babel As far as I know, babel is loaded with the documentclass scrbook

Comment: @Johannes_B Had to install the language 'nohyphenation', now it's working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `\AtEveryCitekey{\hyphenrules{nohyphenation}}` in the preamble, hyphenation can be disabled for all BibLaTeX keys (the langugage `nohyphenation` must be defined in `babel`).

Answer (score 1):

I tried the solution by Robinaut but did not get it to work with `MikTeX 2.9` and Windows 10. I always got the following error:

```
Package babel Error: You haven't defined the language nohyphenation yet.
```

I did also not manage to edit the `languages.ini` like suggested [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/mailman/message/27040821/).

However, I found a working solution. If you have a look in the `languages.ini` there are some languages without hyphenation (they use `zerohyph.tex` as loader). Based on this, you can use one of these languages (e.g. arabic):

```
\AtEveryCitekey{\hyphenrules{arabic}}
```