# Prohibit hyphenation between biblatatex bib label and prefixnumbers

Tags: biblatex, hyphenation

If one uses prefixes for bib labels in biblatex it frequently comes to hyphenation between the prefix and the actual bib label, especially for longer prefixes.

[image]

**How can this be avoided?**

[Solutions offered here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217717/avoid-hyphenation-of-biblatex-labels) don't have any effect. I'm sure [microtype](/questions/tagged/microtype) will fix it in most of the cases, but I'm not always using it and I'd like a more secure solution.

I'm also aware of `\mbox{...}`, but I wouldn't like to put every cite command there manually.

```
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@InProceedings{Baader1989,
  Title                    = {Direct self control of inverter-fed induction machine, a basis for speed control without speed-measurement},
  Author                   = {Baader, U. and Depenbrock, M. and Gierse, Georg},
  Booktitle                = {Industry Applications Society Annual Meeting, 1989., Conference Record of the 1989 IEEE},
  Year                     = {1989},
  Month                    = {Oct},
  Pages                    = {486-492 vol.1},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic,%
            backend=biber,
            maxnames=99,
            maxalphanames=1,    
            backref=true,
            doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,
            backref=false,
            ]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\labelalphaothers}{}

\bibliography{references.bib} 

\begin{document}
\noindent This is a looong sentence which will lead to hyphenation in the bib label:  \cite{Baader1989}
\printbibliography[prefixnumbers = P-]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I get `Package biblatex Warning: prefixnumbers option to \printbibliography is no longer supported, use 'labelprefix' option to \newrefcontext.`

Comment: @egreg I obviously have an older version of biblatex. Does the problem still apply with `labelprefix`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `prefixnumbers` is no longer supported on the most recent version of `biblatex`.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@InProceedings{Baader1989,
  Title                    = {Direct self control of inverter-fed induction machine, a basis for speed control without speed-measurement},
  Author                   = {Baader, U. and Depenbrock, M. and Gierse, Georg},
  Booktitle                = {Industry Applications Society Annual Meeting, 1989., Conference Record of the 1989 IEEE},
  Year                     = {1989},
  Month                    = {Oct},
  Pages                    = {486-492 vol.1},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic,%
            backend=biber,
            maxnames=99,
            maxalphanames=1,    
            backref=true,
            doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,
            backref=false,
            ]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\labelalphaothers}{}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newrobustcmd{\safehyphen}{\ifincsname-\else\mbox{-}\fi}

\begin{document}
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=P\safehyphen]

\noindent This is a looong sentence which will lead to 
hyphenation in the bib label:  \cite{Baader1989}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I believe the same strategy will work with the old way. The problem is that the prefix is used in two distinct places: for printing and for forming a control sequence names, so adding a macro there will not work unless we use the `\ifincsname` trick.

[image]

Note: I tested with TeX Live 2014 and

```
\newrobustcmd{\safehyphen}{\ifincsname-\else\mbox{-}\fi}
```

in the preamble along with

```
\printbibliography[prefixnumbers = P\safehyphen]
```

works.

Comment: This solution just seems to work with pdflatex and not with lualatex. Could you confirm? (I updated Miktex yesterday) I get the error `Missing \endcsname inserted. \endentry` Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: @thewaywewalk Confirmed. It seems something is broken with `\ifincsname`.

Comment: @thewaywewalk It seems to be a long standing bug in LuaTeX: while `\csname T\ifincsname e\else\hbox{e}\fi X\endcsname` works, `\ifcsname T\ifincsname e\else \hbox{e}\fi X\endcsname\fi` raises an error because the false branch is followed.

Comment: thanks for your error analysis! So I guess I have to manually fix the cases where the safehyphen would have been needed.

Comment: @thewaywewalk See http://tug.org/pipermail/luatex/2017-May/006500.html